# GPU produces a 4-beep error code at boot, though not always

Tags: motherboard, gpu, nvidia-geforce, beep-code

## Short version

When booting my computer, the GPU (NVidia GeForce GTX 1070 Founders Edition) emits 4 beeps (1 long, 3 short) and produces no video output. As far as I can tell, the rest of the booting sequence works correctly.

I haven't identified the conditions to reproduce this issue, and it's not on *every* boot, so "random" is the best description of its happenstance so far. Two repair shops were unable to reproduce it or suggest a corrective course.

## Additional information

### Full description

#### Normal boot

My motherboard normally emits one short beep on boot (guess it's its way of saying "hello") and the screen displays its splash almost immediately.

#### Error boot

The motherboard still beeps, but there's no video output.

About half a second after the first beep, there are four more (1 long, 3 short). I was able to track this as GPU error code, but couldn't find its meaning.

### History of the computer

#### Components

This device was custom-made in 2012.

- The motherboard is an Asus P9X79 Pro.
- The initial GPU was an NVidia Quadro 4000 PNY. The Quadro died in 2016, just a few days before the GTX 1070 was released, hence the logical replacement.
- The power supply is a Corsair HX750 (750W).

This problem never occurred with the Quadro, it appeared with the 1070. The BIOS is as up-to-date as can be (2014).

#### Power

I moved since installing the 1070, so it does not appear to be related to the electric network of the lodging (unless both lodgings had equally crappy electricity, but I had no problem with any other device).

I also use a EATON power supply to protect my computer, and had to change it a few months back when the previous one stopped booting (from PowerStation 800 to EL650). I had a short period without one, and it may be a coincidence or just a mistake on my part, but it felt like the problem occurred more at that time.

I had the computer for a diagnostic at a repair shop just two weeks ago, and they had no problem. They always do a video benchmark (I think they used FurMark this time) and never detect anything abnormal.

#### Peripherals

I changed the screens when moving, and it didn't change the frequency of the error.

### Happenstance of the error

The error seems to be random.

- Sometimes, the computer boots fine and I get a nice video output on both screens.
- On other occasions, the error occurs as described above.

There can be a bad streak of boots in error and then, the following day, everything works fine.
There seems to have been an evolution in trends however, and getting the computer to boot properly seems increasingly difficult. Two years back, when I moved, it mainly worked OK and then, for a week, I had issues.

Usually, once the computer is in error, every following attempt will result in an error, too.

### Corrective attempts

I tried some things:

- Pressing the power button while unplugged to empty the electric circuit: seemed to work for a while, but not anymore. If the computer is in error, it won't boot.
- Opening the case to clean dust: when in a very bad streak, this seems to solve the issue for a while, but with decreasing efficiency (used to solve it for a few weeks; last time, there was no dust and it solved it for 36h).

## Wrapping up

I worry about the fact that this error is not an "always" thing, and that the frequency seems to be increasing. I see many posts about a power issue or the GPU being badly connected, but I fail to understand how this could be my case and still boot sometimes.

Any hint appreciated, thanks for having taken the time to have a look at this issue.

Comment: Re-seat the graphics after cleaning the contacts. Keep monitoring its behavior.

Comment: "1 (long) + 3 (short) Conventional or Extended memory failure. Remove added memory, or reseat the installed memory sticks." from [What Are ASUS Beep Codes and How To Identify Them | SoftwareKeep](https://softwarekeep.com/blog/what-are-asus-beep-codes-and-how-to-identify-them)

Comment: This is not the GPU which beeps, but the mother board EFI executing power-on self-tests because it cannot detect a VGA mode on the bus (one continuous beep followed by three short beeps). See [Asus documentation](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA2011/P9X79-PRO/E8037_P9X79_PRO.pdf#page=72).

Comment: That's interesting. I tried reseating the memory sticks, but it didn't change anything. @mins If I read properly the doc, I hear the "one short beep" for VGA detected, and then the "No VGA detected." I'm not sure how to interpret that.

Comment: VGA detected and no keyboard would produce one short beep, but one continuous beep (I assume it's one long beep) and 3 short beeps means VGA not detected. I understand you are in the second case, unfortunately. As VGA is only required for the hardware boot and early Windows start phase, a defective VGA mode after the boot may occur silently, but if you can test VGA mode after a successful boot, while running, you may see some failures.

Comment: @Chop VGA here does not necessarily mean your graphics card, but whether a monitor has been plugged in (or even, turned on, in at least some cases of HDMI/DP). I can't tell what exactly the cause is there, but you might want to try another video cable. Also DVI tends to be less buggy when it comes to this sort of detection stuff, you may want to use it instead if it's acceptable (even a passive HDMI to DVI cable / adapter could help, as long as the monitor side is DVI).

Comment: Thanks @TomYan. In desperation, I opened the computer some weeks ago, totally removed, then replugged the graphics card, and things have been smooth since then (well, I have some other minor glitches, but nothing related to that issue).

Comment: For people who would be coming here today, one year later, the problem occurred again. Each time it does, I open the panel, press the GPU in place, and everything works fine for a few weeks. Some hours of gaming seem to accelerate the return of the issue, can't tell if it's related to heat, vibrations (ventirads) or both. Annoying, but I survive.